# Как правильно: повышение культуры?

Tags: стилистика, лексика

Как правильно сформулировать: "Повышение экономической культуры"  или "повышение уровня экономической культуры"?

Answer (score 1):

Есть выражение "Человек высокой культуры", бывает "низкая культура", а значит, ее можно повысить! Одно из значений этого слова - высокий уровень чего-нибудь (культура производства, культура речи), то есть "повышение уровня культуры" в каком-то смысле тавтология. Правильнее сказать: "Повышать культуру", но я не понимаю, что значит "экономическая культура". Лучше назвать это экономическими знаниями.

Answer (score 0):

Второе. Культуру повысить нельзя, а вот уровень — запросто. Можно еще сказать: "повышение культурного уровня".